# Divide Dataframe into 4 equal groups and visualize into stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been working through different iterations of this, but keep coming up short. I am hoping for some guidance on how I can split my dataframe into 4 equal groups(based on totals for each variable).

After that, I would like to visualize each group into a stacked bar chart. I am new to this, so any input would help a lot.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

list <- list(BOS= 134,CUN=205,FLL= 114,HNL =  95, LAS = 288, LAX = 218, 
LGA = 456, LGW = 169, MBJ = 71, MCO = 223, OGG = 99, PHX = 167, PSP = 86, 
PVR = 80, RSW = 44, SFO = 44, SNA = 196, YBR = 43, 
YDF = 93, YEG = 2773, YFC = 114, YHM = 98, YHZ = 1266, YKF = 47, YLW = 482, 
YMM = 239, YOW = 1097,YQB = 141, YQM = 80, YQQ = 102, YQR = 334, YQT = 167, 
YQU = 85, YQY = 45, YUL = 1210, YVR = 5298, 
YWG = 1257, YXE = 357, YXJ = 42, YXS = 111, YXT = 67, YXU = 130, YXX = 128, 
YYC = 7737, YYG = 55, YYJ = 335, YYT = 475, YYZ = 13283, YZF = 55)
```

# Data Frame

```
DF = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,list))
DF$name = rownames(DF)
colnames(DF)[colnames(DF)=="V1"] = "total"

DF <- data.frame(DF$name, opsDF$total)
DF <-rename(DF, c("DF.name"="Base", "opsDF.total"="Total"))
DF <- DF[order(DF$Total,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

# Plot

I am trying to split this plot into 4 equal groups - according to each base total - then visualize into a new stacked bar chart.

```
 ggplot(DF, aes(x = reorder(Base, Total), y = Total, label = Total, fill= 
 Base, colour = Total)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")  + 
  scale_fill_hue(l=40, c=35) + ggtitle("Log Entries") + 
    geom_text(size = 5, vjust = 0.3, color = "black", angle = 0, nudge_x =0, 
     nudge_y = 200) + theme_minimal() + xlab("Base") + ylab("Entries") + 
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0, size = 10, 
          face = "bold"), axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = 
              "bold")) + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
          guides(fill=FALSE) + coord_flip()
```

[image: Version 1 chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dummy variable `DF$part` to generate groups which will afterwards be visualized with `facets` in ggplot.

```
n <- nrow(DF)
DF$part <- sort(rep_len(1:4, length.out = n))
```

These groups are then of equal size (if possible).

```
table(DF$part)
#  1  2  3  4 
# 13 12 12 12 

ggplot(DF, aes(x = reorder(Base, Total), y = Total, label = Total, fill= 
                 Base, colour = Total)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")  + 
  scale_fill_hue(l=40, c=35) + ggtitle("Log Entries") + 
  geom_text(size = 5, vjust = 0.3, color = "black", angle = 0, nudge_x =0, 
            nudge_y = 200) + theme_minimal() + xlab("Base") + ylab("Entries") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0, size = 10, 
                                   face = "bold"), axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = 
                                                                               "bold")) + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  guides(fill=FALSE) + coord_flip()  + 
## add this line to your ggplot
  facet_wrap(~part, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Have a look at the options of `scales` argument in `facet_wrap` (see `?facet_wrap`) to change the behavior of the facets x and y axes.

---

NOTE:

you could also stack them by setting `aes(x = reorder(part, Total))`... However, this might end up in unreadable text annotations and box colors etc.

Comment: Thanks loki, this helps. I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to group these four plots by what is the most equitable distribution, based on total entries. 

e.g. YYZ has 3-4 small bases in a group while YEG would have the most.

Comment: In order to do that, I would suggest to search for something like "find similar string patterns". Since this Q was about how to generate 4 equal sized groups, I think this would be too broad.